# iOS: popping up a subview in a tabview

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, tabview

Newbie question for iOS -- I'm really confused with how navigation view works in a tabview.

Right now I have a tabview that has 2 views. In the second tab I have a button.  When the button is clicked I'd like a new window to show up with some information, and the new window needs a Back button on top that goes back to the second tab.

I followed some tutorials and put a `NavigationController` in **secondTab.xib**, added the line

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

to **secondTab.h**, and

```
NewWindowController *newWindow = [[NewWindowController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewWindowController" bundle: nil];
[self.navController pushViewController:newWindow animated:YES];
NSLog(@"clicked");
```

to my button implementation for `-(IBAction) click: (id)sender`

When I clicked the button in my second tab, the log shows "clicked" but my view is not changing.

Is there some setting I need to change for File's Owner/Navigation Controller outlets/referencing outlets etc...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a property for the UINavigationController, you want to push onto the current navigation controller like so:

```
NewWindowController *newWindow = [[NewWindowController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewWindowController" bundle: nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newWindow animated:YES];
NSLog(@"clicked");
```

When a UIViewController is associated with a UINavigationController (i.e. it's part of a navigation controller hierarchy) then its `navigationController` property will be set, so you can access it like I've shown.

Comment: Still nothing is showing. I think maybe it's because I don't have a navigationController in the beginning. The code in my appDelegate is:
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Comment: I added a navigationView to the rootViewController, now it works :)